# Using an assignment operator with class instance and vector

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have a class called node defined in a header file ClassDefinition.h

```
#ifndef CLASS_DEFINITION_H // if-not-defined
#define CLASS_DEFINITION_H // define
#endif                     // end-if


#include<vector>

class node{
public:

std::string name;
std::vector<std::string> child_node_vector;
std::vector<int> child_distance_vector;
bool is_visited;



node& operator=(const node &rhs)
{
    child_distance_vector = rhs.child_distance_vector;
    child_node_vector = rhs.child_node_vector;
    is_visited = rhs.is_visited;
    name = rhs.name;
    return *this;
}

};
```

In another source code file I have some nodes defined and a vector to hold these nodes Map_Info_Reader.cpp

```
#include <ClassDefinition.h>
node Eforie;
node Vaslui;
node Iasi;
node Neamt;
std::vector<node> node_list;
node_list[0] = Eforie;
node_list[1] = Vaslui;
node_list[2] = Iasi;
node_list[3] = Neamt;
(other class variables are set further down in file)
```

Both of these are called from my main source code file DFS_Agent.cpp

```
#include <Class_Definition.h>
#include <Map_Info_Reader.h>

void Move_To_Node(node){

node current_node = Vaslui;
std::vector<std::string> Search_Queue;
Search_Queue.resize(1);
Search_Queue[0] = "Vaslui"

for (int i = 0; i<node_list.size(); i++)
{
    if (Search_Queue[0] == node_list[i].name)
    {
        current_node = node_list[i];

    }
}
```

}
I get a compiler error: no operator "=" matches these operands. Operand types are node = node from line 
    current_node = node_list[i]

Comment: For which line in your code do you get the error message?

Comment: good practice is return reference`node& operator=(const node &rhs)`

Comment: @SebastianDressler for the line current_node = node_list[i];

Comment: What you have posted compiles fine for me. Could you post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @ChrisDrew I'm using visual studio express 2012, would that make a difference in compiling?

Comment: Just to embellish /u/triclosan's answer, you need a `return *this;` at the end of the assignment operator. are there any other exceptions

Comment: @IdeaHat Thanks, I have updated the question a bit. The class is defined in a header file, and is included in my main source code file. If the class is defined in the same file as the source code, it works fine??

Comment: That's not an MCVE. [This is an example of an MCVE](http://rextester.com/GIRTS79527). But it compiles fine (on Visual Studio).

Comment: @ChrisDrew it works fine when all source code is in one file, but when the class is defined separately is fails

Comment: An example where the class is defined separately would be fine but try to reduce it to the minimum required to reproduce the problem and then post  _all_ the code.

Comment: `void Move_To_Node(node){` looks weird for me

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need overloaded assignment operator at all in your case. For `std::vector`, `bool`, `std::string` you may omit it.

Anyway if you decide to use your own make it something like

```
node& operator=(const node &rhs)
{
    if (this != &rhs) // protect against invalid self-assignment
    {
        this->child_distance_vector = rhs.child_distance_vector;
        this->child_node_vector = rhs.child_node_vector;
        this->is_visited = rhs.is_visited;
        this->name = rhs.name;
    }
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: Whilst this is true, it doesn't explain why OP gets an error message.